# in Salesforce1, How to create "specific object button" that redirect to a lightning page with is object as parameter

Tags: salesforce1-app, custom-button, lightning-apps, custom-link

I'm developping an application usable in salesforce1.
I'm embedding a complex html screen that would manage data about a custom object in a lightning app/component

To access this screen, I would like to add a custom button to my custom object page layout that would redirect to my lightning app/component.
In addition, this lightning component need no know which record to work on. So i need to pass it as parameter.

I've seen how to create such button to redirect to canvas, visualforce page, or action triggering, but not to lightning app/component.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

DemoMan, you can pass attribute values to Lightning apps similarly to how you can pass page parameters to Visualforce pages, using URL parameter name-value pairs. Take a look at the [Component Attributes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_attributes.htm) section in the *Lightning Components Developer's Guide*, looking specifically for the sentence that starts, "Now, append `?whom=you` to the URL and reload the page."

Comment: neither from Setup > Create > Objects > myCustomOject > Buttons, Links, and Actions > New Action
nor from Setup > Create > Objects > myCustomOject > Buttons, Links, and Actions > New Button or Link , i can't find a way to redirect to a lightning component.  Using  sf1 in my browser, my lightning component is accessible through https://eu3.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#{"componentDef":"one:auraContainer","attributes":{"values":{"tag":"salesTool:form"}},"t":1415264070302}, but i don't think i can simply make a url redirect to this url

Comment: Hello, @DemoMan, you need to create a [Lightning Application](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apps_overview.htm) as your top-level container. According to the docs, "On a production server, the `.app` resource is the only addressable unit in a browser URL."